# Firebase Realtime Database Security Failing to Read Closure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am writing a security rule in firebase to validate that either a post exists or a group exists. I fully understand that security rules are not filters and I am not using it as a filter, but as a validation metric. This is the rule I am trying to implement...

```
    "notifications": {
  ".read": "auth !== null",
  ".write": "auth !== null",
  ".indexOn": ["post_ID", "group_ID"],
  "$userID": {
    "$notifID": {
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['has-seen', 'end-time', 'time', 'user_ID', 'username']) && $userID !== newData.child('sender_ID').val() && (root.child('groups').child(newData.child('group_ID').val()).exists() || root.child('follower-feed-storage').child(newData.child('post_ID').val()).exists())",
      ".write": "auth.uid !== $userID && !data.exists()",
    }
  }
},
```

Clearly, the rule should evaluate the hasChildren and $userID !== newData.child('user_ID').val() condition properly which it does. However, when it should evaluate the last expression after the && and inside the parenthesis, it will either succeed or fail based on the first condition inside the parenthesis and not perform the or operator and evaluate the second expression. Clearly I am doing something wrong with the syntax but I cant figure it out. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a `string` to `.child` so if `newData.child('group_ID').val()` evaluates to `null` or `undefined`, then it will fail. Try casting the result of that to a `string` or test whether that exists before looking it up. (I recommend the latter.)

```
(newData.child('group_ID').exists() && root.child('groups').child(newData.child('group_ID').val()).exists())
```

Comment: Beautiful, I wasn't clear this was required from reading the documentation. Works like a charm now